# Racket self-writing code function

Tags: reflection, racket

Let's say I have DrRacket open with a source file with some code in it and a part of the code writes code in the same file. I did this with `open-output-file` and I can't see the code updating in DrRacket.

Is there a function or a methodology to write code in DrRacket that writes code that is then evaluated and in the same time I can see the code in the IDE after it is written for rapid-feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
DrRacket (And all IDEs and text editors) writes into a buffer, which then is written into a file when  you click 'save'. It does not maintain a constant stream of checking the source file for changes. If it did, it would be substantially slower. Even closing and opening the file in DrRacket would force you not to save, because the buffer overwrites the file.